# File sharing token retrieval using SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile fails for temporary files

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-runtime, storage-file-share

I am writing an UWP application. I am trying to generate a file sharing token for an email attachment opened with my App. However, this is raising an exception "Access denied"

```
    //App.xaml
    protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args){
         String sharingToken = SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile((StorageFile)args.Files[0]);
    }
```

Is there any alternative to share a temporary file between UWP apps?

Comment: I have tested with add the specific file with fileopen picker, it works well, could you check 
if  args.Files contains file?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, Not by using the filepicker, if you try to open an email attachment with the UWP app, then  `SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile((StorageFile)args.Files[0])` is giving access denied error.

Comment: Could you mind share a code sample that could reproduce this problem?